# consoletvs/charts how to use percentage

Tags: laravel, chart.js

I'm using this library in laravel 10, but I can't find examples of using the options, only with js. I tried to do it, but I couldn't.
I need to make a pie graph with percentage, can anyone help me how to do it?

```
$volumeOrderDistributorChartjs = new VolumeOrdersDistributor;
        $volumeOrderDistributorChartjs->labels($nameDistributors);
        $volumeOrderDistributorChartjs->options(['tooltip' => [
            'show' => true,
        ]]);
        $volumeOrderDistributorChartjs->dataset('Quantidade de litros solicitados', 'bar', $quantityLitersRequestedChartjs)->options([
            'backgroundColor' => '#2E86C1',
        ]);
        $volumeOrderDistributorChartjs->dataset('Quantidade de litros validados', 'bar', $quantityLitersValidatedChartjs)->options([
            'backgroundColor' => '#CB4335',
        ]);
```

My code is like this and the value I'm passing is not a percentage, it's whole numbers. I'm passing the integer, because if I pass the percentage, it doesn't show